# Run local Java Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, git-bash

I'm going through the Heroku Getting Started for Java, but I'm having trouble running the example app locally.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#run-the-app-locally
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#define-a-procfile

After I run it, I get the "starting web.1 on port 5000", but when I open localhost:5000, it just gives me "This webpage is not available."

Here is the output from CLI

```
$ heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
web.1  | in the version search
web.1  |            show splash screen with specified image
web.1  |
```

Let me know if you need more information.

UPDATE:  So I actually ran the command on my own, when I realized, that's all that Procfile does, and the last line I get is

```
sh.exe": target\dependency\*: No such file or directory
```

When this is obviously is a target\dependency made from mvn clean install?
What am I typing wrong?

```
$ java -cp target\classes;"target\dependency\*" Main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a lot to do with compatibility.

What I didn't mention, which had a lot to do with it, was that I was running this on GitBash.  So it was taking everything differently.

Ex.  I had to escape the semicolon for the cp argument.

Short story the Procfile.windows should be

```
web: java -cp target/classes\;target/dependency/* Main
```

no quotes anywhere...
I'm leaving this up in case anyone else has issues

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotes should have the same effect as using the backslash in this case; i.e. `java -cp "target/classes;target/dependency/*" Main` should also work.

Comment: Also, thanks very much @mc805 for flagging this and providing an answer so soon afterwards. It was very helpful and I'd upvote if I had the reputation.